# Rails 5: Calling a service class - relation mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service, devise

I am trying to learn how to write a service class in my rails 5 app.

When a user registers with devise, I'm trying to incorporate a service class that makes models associated with the user's account on creation of the user account.

In my devise registrations controller, I have:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  def create
    super do |user|
      if user.persisted?
        User::CompleteRegistration.call(user: user)
      end
    end
  end

  protected



  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, ])
  end


  private

end
```

In my app / services/ user folder, I have a file called: complete_registration.rb:

```
class User::CompleteRegistration #< ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.call(user: u)
      new(user: user).call
    end

    def initialize(user: u)
      self.user = user
    end

    def call
      Profile::SetupService.call(user: user)
      Setting::SetupService.call(user: user)
      User::OrganisationMapperService.new(user: user).call
    end

    # def join_an_organisation
    #   render "organisation_requests/new"
    # end

    private

    attr_accessor :user
end
```

When I try to save this and then sign up as a user, I can see an error message that says:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant User::CompleteRegistrations:
```

I note that it has pluralised the word 'registration'. I don't know if this has something to do with the problem. I tried saving the file as a plural, and renaming the class as a plural, but that didn't work.

The actual error rendered says:

```
PG::UndefinedTable at /users
ERROR:  relation "complete_registration_services" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"complete_registration_se...
```

I cant expand the message to get more detail, but there is no relation to be found, because it isnt an active record table that I'm trying to call.

I also tried adding a callback to my user model as an alternative solution:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :after_confirmation_setup
def after_confirmation_setup
    return unless !self.confirmed_at.blank?
      User::CompleteRegistration.call(user: @user)
  end
```

But that doesnt work either.

Can anyone see how I can setup my app to call a service class on user create (from the registration controller, or any other method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of things, this seems like a naming issue.
From first appearances (I can't say definatively without actually using your code base in console and debugging) but based on a quick scan and looking at the errors you are receiving this appears to be one of Ruby's quirks which I have bumped into a few times.

You have a User class in the global scope (In your models directory), and you have a service class User::CompleteRegistration, which when you call from somewhere is perfectly logical to assume will point to the defined User::CompleteRegistration class. However, Ruby doesn't see it like that.

`User::CompleteRegistration` can be split into two parts, first User:: Is evaluated, and Ruby searches for a User class, and grabs your model. It then evaluates the CompleteRegistration, and looks for a defined CompleteRegistration that can be used in your User class. This is may be why you are getting the error about a relation. It is searching for a relation within the User model scope.

So essentially, when you write `User::CompleteRegistration` Ruby doesnt say *Right! lets grab a User::CompleteRegistration class!* Ruby says *Right! lets grab a CompleteRegistration class that can be used within the User scope!*

To prevent this, I would perhaps change the naming of your service to something more simple, like: `Registration::Complete` and avoid any overlapping of class / module names within the global scope.

also on a side note, I too love using services in code, and I don't really want to write a shameless plug on SO but perhaps it your case it can help? I have written a [gem to provide easy to use services](https://github.com/John-Hayes-Reed/bottled_services) that has an implementation not too dissimilar to what you are using, perhaps it could be of use, whether you use it as a gem or just scan the code in it, I hope somehow maybe it can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. This is really helpful. I'll definitely give your gem a try too. Thanks  again.